# ASP.NET CORE 3.1 Custom Identity ASP.Net Issue

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

i am getting following error when posting data

[image]

The output of this request is

[image]

My Code in Controller and Startup class is as below

**Startup Class**

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
            {
              
    
                services.AddSingleton<IRoleDao, RoleDao>();
                services.AddSingleton<IRoleDao, RoleDao>();
                services.AddSingleton<IUserDao, UserDao>();
                services.AddSingleton<IUserRoleDao, UserRoleDao>();
                services.AddSingleton<IUserClaimsDao, UserClaimsDao>();
               
    
                services.AddIdentity<AppUser, AppRole>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();
                services.AddTransient<IUserStore<AppUser>, UserStore>();
                services.AddTransient<IRoleStore<AppRole>, RoleStore>();
    
    
                //services.AddScoped<IIdentityAccountService, AccountService>();
    
                services.AddScoped<JwtTokenGenerator>();
                services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                    .AddJwtBearer(options => options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateIssuer = false,
                        ValidateAudience = false,
                        ValidAudience = Configuration["Jwt:ValidAudience"],
                        ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:ValidIssuer"],
                        ValidateLifetime = true,
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
                    });
    
                services.AddControllers(options =>
                {
                    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
                    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
                });
    
    
                services.AddAuthorization(options =>
                {
                    options.AddPolicy("DeleteClaimPolicy", policy => policy.RequireClaim("DeleteClaim"));
                    options.AddPolicy("AddClaimPolicy", policy => policy.RequireClaim("CreateClaim"));
                });
    
              
            }
    
            // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
            {
               
    
                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                }
    
                app.UseRouting();
                app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
                app.UseAuthentication();
                app.UseAuthorization();
                app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
                {
                    endpoints.MapControllers();
                });
            }
```

**ControllerClass**

```
 [ApiController]
        [Route("[controller]")]
        public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
        {
            private readonly JwtTokenGenerator _jwtTokenGenerator;
           
            private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
            {
                "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
            };
    
            private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;
    
            public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger, JwtTokenGenerator jwtTokenGenerator)
            {
                _logger = logger;
                _jwtTokenGenerator = jwtTokenGenerator;
            }
    
            [HttpGet]
            public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
            {
                var rng = new Random();
                return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
                {
                    Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
                    TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
                    Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
                })
                .ToArray();
            }
    
            [AllowAnonymous]
            [HttpGet("login")]
            [ProducesResponseType(typeof(Result), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
            [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
            [ProducesResponseType(typeof(Result), StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
            public string Login()
            {
                string token = _jwtTokenGenerator.CreateUserToken("Test");
                return token;
            }
    
            [HttpPost("create")]
            [Authorize(Policy = "AddClaimPolicy")]
            [ProducesResponseType(typeof(Result), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
            [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
            [ProducesResponseType(typeof(Result), StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
            public string CreateClaim()
            {
                return "Created Claim";
            }
    
            [HttpDelete("delete")]
            [Authorize(Policy = "DeleteClaimPolicy")]
            [ProducesResponseType(typeof(Result), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
            [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
            [ProducesResponseType(typeof(Result), StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
            public string DeleteClaim()
            {
                return "Deleted Claim";
            }
        }
```

However the when i comment the following line of code in ConfigureServices Method of Startup class

```
  services.AddIdentity<AppUser, AppRole>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();
  services.AddTransient<IUserStore<AppUser>, UserStore>();
  services.AddTransient<IRoleStore<AppRole>, RoleStore>();
```

I get the desired output

[image]

[image]

On Closer observation, A second request to login is been called.

Please note that i am using custom implementation

**GET /Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fweatherforecast%2Fcreate HTTP/1.1**

**Can someone please correct me if i am missing something.**

Answer (score 0):

The above is solved, just changed

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                    .AddJwtBearer(options => options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateIssuer = false,
                        ValidateAudience = false,
                        ValidAudience = Configuration["Jwt:ValidAudience"],
                        ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:ValidIssuer"],
                        ValidateLifetime = true,
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
                    });
```

to

```
 services.AddAuthentication(x =>
        {
            x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
         .AddJwtBearer(options => options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
         {
             ValidateIssuer = false,
             ValidateAudience = false,
             ValidAudience = Configuration["Jwt:ValidAudience"],
             ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:ValidIssuer"],
             ValidateLifetime = true,
             ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
             IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
         });
```

The parameter  x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

is required to avoid redirection to Login

**> GET /Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fapi%2FLSPAccount%2Frole%2Fcreate HTTP/1.1

> Host: localhost:9000
> User-Agent: insomnia/6.6.2
> Content-Type: application/json
> Accept: */***